# Data factory Copy to temporary table

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm trying to follow the simple best practice instructions from MS on how to copy bulk data into azure sql using data factory:

[Best Practice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sql-server#best-practice-for-loading-data-into-sql-server)

"Option 1: When you have a large amount of data to copy, use the following approach to do an upsert:

First, use a temporary table to bulk load all records by using the copy activity. Because operations against temporary tables aren't logged, you can load millions of records in seconds.
...
for example, ##UpsertTempTable, as the table name in the dataset. "

I've followed those instructions and it fails to copy the data. If I use a real table, rather than a temp table it's fine. The real table gets created on the fly and the data imports successfully

Here is the JSON for the dataset

```
{
"name": "UserTempTable",
"properties": {
    "linkedServiceName": {
        "referenceName": "AzureSqlDatabase1",
        "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
    },
    "annotations": [],
    "type": "AzureSqlTable",
    "schema": [],
    "typeProperties": {
        "table": "usertemptable"
    }
},
"type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets"
}
```

If I replace "usertemptable" with "##usertemptable"

it fails

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you reference where you found this info, and also explain how it fails - if there's an error message, post it. If there is no error message, explain the expected behaviour, i.e. "I ran SELECT * FROM ##usertemptable but there was no data"

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57318173/1059001 for answer to similar question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data Factory doesn't support auto create temporary table. We can not set "##usertemptable" as the table name:
[image]

**ERROR**:

```
{
    "errorCode": "2200",
    "message": "ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A database operation failed. Please search error to get more details.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.InvalidOperationException,Message=Cannot access destination table '[dbo].[##temptest]'.,Source=System.Data,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Invalid object name '##temptest'.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=208,Class=16,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=0,Errors=[{Class=16,Number=208,State=0,Message=Invalid object name '##temptest'.,},],'",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Copy data1",
    "details": []
}
```

For Azure SQL database, the temporary tables are in TempDB, but we can not see and access it in System Database. We also can not choose the temporary table as dataset in Data Factory.

> Global temporary tables are automatically dropped when the session that created the table ends and all other tasks have stopped referencing them. The association between a task and a table is maintained only for the life of a single Transact-SQL statement. This means that a global temporary table is dropped at the completion of the last Transact-SQL statement that was actively referencing the table when the creating session ended.

You can reference this link [How to create temp tables in SQL to be used in several ADF activities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56119601/how-to-create-temp-tables-in-sql-to-be-used-in-several-adf-activities). It give you a lot of helps and suggestions.

You also can referece this blog: [Using global temporary table in copy activity not working](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/35449). Microsoft MSFT gives you an another way that you can insert the data to temporary table with stored procedure.

Some notice: Don't close the SQL connection session when the temporary table created.

If all of this don't work for you, you may need think about why you insist to use temporary table since Copy Active have good performance to copy data. The final choice may be that using the real table rather than temporary table.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I thought the issue of the temporary table between the activities would be a problem, but I didn't even get past the table create to try! Shame MS don;t update their documentation to remove the instructions. I have decided to approach by creating a parameter with the pipeline ID and using that as the table name. Just got to remember to remove the table at the end of the process.

Comment: If you want to be proactive you can raise a GitHub issue on the doc. If you don't want to do that you could edit your question to link to the doco and maybe I'll do it.

Comment: Thanks updated the question. I'm not a github user, but will give it a go

Comment: I think it's been raised already [link](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/35449)

Comment: You're right - it has already been raised. It's disappointing that they put non functioning suggestions in their doco and even more disappointing that it hasn't been removed after it was identifed _6 months ago_

Answer (score 1):

There is new feature available in sql so that instead of creating temp table use table type. Its quite easy to implement as well.