# ADF - Access #table or Temp table used in Script task activity output to be used in Copy activity as source

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-data-factory

We have simple script consider the one below as an example.

Script :

```
create table #tableABC (
    col A varchar(10),
    col B varchar(10),
    col C varchar(10)
)

insert into #tableABC
    select 'A' ,'B', 'C'
```

The above script is considered as an SP and excepted in script task and it works.
but we are unable to access the #table in the following copy activity

```
select * from #tableABC;
```

[image]

Comment: Not only do `#temp` tables have a limited lifetime (they are automatically disposed when their creator goes out of scope) they also have a limited visibility: they can only be seen on the connection that created them. Have you considered that `#temp` tables may not be appropriate for what you're attempting to do?

Comment: _The above script is considered as an SP_ Either it IS a stored procedor or it is not. There is no "considered". Don't add confusion by using terminology incorrectly. And using a temp table of hardcoded values as input into a second task makes no sense. Your last image (please don't use images generally) also shows yet another global temp table usage as well. This sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) resulting from more significant design issues.

Comment: my bad its a ## table a global table :create table #tableABC 
( col A varchar(10), col B varchar(10), col C varchar(10)) 
insert into #tableABC select 'A' ,'B', 'C

Answer (score 0):

Azure data factory doesn't support automatic temporary table creation and we cannot set table name with ## as starting.

1. TempDB is the location where we can find the temporary tables. We cannot choose the temporary tables as datasets in ADF

[How to create temp tables in SQL to be used in several ADF activities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56119601/how-to-create-temp-tables-in-sql-to-be-used-in-several-adf-activities)

Refer the above link, which has lot of suggestions.

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/35449

Also refer the above blog for additional support.

Note: Do not close the SQL connection session after creating temporary table.

**Alternate suggestion:**

Instead of using the Temp Tables, use the ***table type*** for easy usage.

Comment: yeah thnks table type works!!!